# Convergence of a Particular Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I was supposed to use the convergence tests to determine whether the following series converges, converges absolutely, or diverges.

Almost every test I used was inconclusive, the series is :
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k  \frac{k\ln(k)}{(k+1)^3}.$$

Comment: For convergence/divergence, use the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

For absolute convergence, do a [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) with $\frac{1}{k^{1.5}}$.

Comment: Have you used the Leibniz criterion? This concludes the convergence of the series.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 1):

Consider,

$$f(x)=\frac{x \ln x}{(x+1)^3}$$

Then,

$$f'(x)=\frac{x-2x\ln x+\ln x+1}{(x+1)^4}$$

One can show that for $x>3$ that we must have $x-2x\ln x+\ln x+1<0$ by considering the monotonically decreasing function $g(x)=x-2x\ln x+\ln x+1$ defined on $(1,\infty)$. I leave it to you to fill in the gaps. Thus we have for $x>3$ that $f'(x)<0$. Hence it follows that,

$$\frac{n \ln n}{(n+1)^3}$$

Is eventually decreasing, and your series converges by the alternating series test.

Answer (score 1):

You have that
$$
\frac{n\ln n}{(n+1)^3} \sim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{n^2}
$$
so that, since the (positive) series $\sum_n \frac{\ln n}{n^2}$ converges *(e.g., by comparison with a $p$-series $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$)* by theorems of comparison the series
$\sum_n (-1)^n \frac{n\ln n}{(n+1)^3}$ converges *absolutely*.